# xtext becomes very slow and needs much more memory to generate Xtext artifacts when the grammar is larger and larger

Tags: xtext

My grammar may be a little larger (about 350 lines). xtext becomes very slow and needs much more memory to generate Xtext artifacts when the grammar is larger and larger.

```
-Xmx12096m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Comment: 12GB sounds way to much. any chance you can share something that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Is it possible for you to make your grammar available to one of the Xtext committers?

If you can make it available publicly, please file an issue here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues

If it's confidential, but one of the committers could have a look, you could send an email to one of them.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot share it. Could you please let me know if there is limitation/guideline of the size of the grammar? Or we can split it into multiple xtext files?

Comment: I've seen grammars around 1000 or 1500 LOC that work just fine. Splitting up the grammar does not help, because internally Xtext flattens the grammar (inline inherited grammars) before processing it. I understand that sometimes code can not be shared. There is commercial support that also involves signing an NDA. If you prefer to proceed the public way, you can: (a) anonymize you grammar so that the problem remains reproducible but nobody can guess what you're actually working on. (b) Analyze what what Java classes have so many instances that you run out of memory.

Comment: We take use of Unordered Groups in many rules. and many duplicated group items among different rules. We got many warning like: warning(200): ../com.sap.anw.metamodel.ide/src-gen/com/sap/anw/metamodel/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalFin.g:980:1: Decision can match input such as "'category:' 'PAYMENT'" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3, 8
As a result, alternative(s) 3,8 were disabled for that input. I am not sure if this effects. thanks for your answer.